# fancybox put title on top and stay there

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I'm working with Fancybox 2.0 and I want the titlebox to appear above the image or on top of the image, not below.

Just above all content.

I tried to make the `fancybox-inner` style `position:absolute`, but then the height of the `fancybox-wrap` wont be set to absolute pixels.

Could someone help me achieve that?

Answer (score 10):

Best and simplest - using the helpers:

```
helpers : {
            title : {
                type: 'inside',
                position : 'top'
            }
        }
```

Comment: that works with v2.1.x but not with v2.0.x (the version used by the OP), nevertheless the OP required `not below the image or on top of the image. just above all content.`

Answer (score 6):

Add the following fancybox CSS for these elements...

```
.fancybox-title{position: absolute;top: 0;} 

.fancybox-skin{position: relative;}
```

That should put the title at the top.

Answer (score 3):

This code on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JYzqR/.

```js
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
  helpers : {
    title: {
      type: 'inside',          
      position: 'top'
    }
  },
  nextEffect: 'fade',
  prevEffect: 'fade'
});
```

```css
.fancybox-title {
  padding: 0 0 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<a rel="gallery" title="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin imperdiet augue et magna interdum hendrerit" class="fancybox" href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/oZFno.jpg"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/eZSbk.jpg" alt=""/></a>
<a rel="gallery" title="Proin imperdiet augue et magna interdum hendrerit" class="fancybox" href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/tv3kk.jpg"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/IWWbG.jpg" alt=""/></a>

<!-- External Resources -->
<!-- jQuery --><script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- fancybox --><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/2.1.5/jquery.fancybox.min.js"></script>
```

Read "Set title at the top" there http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#examples

Answer (score 2):

From default Fancybox 2.0.6 CSS, replace the following:

```
.fancybox-title {
    position: absolute;
    top: -36px;
    left: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    font: normal 13px/20px "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    position: relative;
    text-shadow: none;
    z-index: 8050;
    }

.fancybox-title-float-wrap {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 8030;
    }
```

This positions the header top left, where it looks best in my opinion.
Here's a screengrab:

[image]

Comment: Can't you post a Fiddle or at least the FancyBox initialization to see your solution at work?

Comment: Download FancyBox, tweak the demo CSS as mentioned above, and that's it.

Comment: The point was to have a working example to complement your answer, but here you have it: [Fiddle!](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/KHyWF/2/)

Comment: +'d your answer, by the most efficient solution! ps: I have my moments ;)

Answer (score 1):

To place the title on top, by the use of Jquery, you can manipulate the relevant CSS using the Fancybox callbacks, when the contents are loaded load, by using `beforeLoad` or `afterLoad`, and when the Fancybox gets updated, with `onUpdate`.

So, you have some callbacks available to best fit your needs: [Link to FancyBox Docs](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#docs)

---

Lets assume that you are loading your fancybox with the code bellow, and to manipulate the title position, you can call the "*onUpdate*" and "*afterLoad*" to trigger that change:

**JQUERY EXAMPLE**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#my_popup_id").fancybox({
    "onUpdate"  : function() {
      $(".fancybox-title").css({'top':'0px', 'bottom':'auto'});
    },
    "afterLoad" : function() {
      $(".fancybox-title").css({'top':'0px', 'bottom':'auto'});
    }
  });
});
```

---

Now, the above example places the [Fancybox](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/) title on top, but if you need it outside, away from the frame, you need to set a negative value to "top", but take into consideration that the frame cannot occupy the entire screen, hence the width and height parameters at this new example:

**JQUERY EXAMPLE 2**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#my_popup_id").fancybox({
    "autoSize"  : false,
    "width"     : '70%',
    "height"    : '70%',
    "onUpdate"  : function() {
      $(".fancybox-title").css({'top':'-30px', 'bottom':'auto'});
    },
    "afterLoad" : function() {
      $(".fancybox-title").css({'top':'-30px', 'bottom':'auto'});
    }
  });
});
```

Check the provided link for the documentation, specially the tab "callbacks".

---

**EDITED:**

And here it is, [the Fiddle link!](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/KHyWF/)

**NEW EDIT NOTES:**

[neokio](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10526600/352449) pointed out a solution with just a simple tweak to the [Fancybox style sheet](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.0.6), so, indeed for a simple title position control, it is the [best approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10526600/352449).

The one present on this answer is useful for some more complex CSS manipulations.

---

**EDITED:** And a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/KHyWF/2/) with the solution presented by neokio!

Comment: This solutions works, a down vote should come with some idea of what's wrong! Cannot learn it if no one points out the error!

Answer (score 0):

Neokio is on the right track, but I think this is a little less destructive of the original code by just adding a new class style to the stylesheet and then referencing that.

```
// Put at bottom of jquery.fancybox.css, change as needed
.fancybox-title-top-wrap {
  position: absolute;
  top: -30px;
  left: 0;
  background: transparent; /* Fallback for web browsers that doesn't support RGBa */
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 2px #222;
  color: #FFF;
  padding: 2px 20px;
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

Then just use:

```
helpers: { title: 'top' }
```

You don't lose any of the original styles, and you can keep adding styles as you need them.

Answer (score 0):

Chris Mackie's answer is the cleanest. No mucking about with `afterUpload` etc. The only thing you can add to push the top of the FancyBox down is the margins:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

      $('.fancybox').fancybox({
                    padding      : 0,
          margin       : [60, 60, 20, 60],
          autoSize     : false, 
          autoCenter   : true,
          fitToView    : true,
          openEffect   : 'fade',
          closeEffect  : 'fade',
          openSpeed    : 100,
          closeSpeed   : 100,
          width        : 900,
          height       : 600
     });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Override fancybox's default css by either adding the below snippet *after* you include fancybox.css

```
// set modal title above container (overriding default bottom)
.fancybox-title-float-wrap {
  bottom: auto;
  top: -35px;
}
```

or, if you use a build system (use GruntJS here) with LESS, then it's as easy as doing in your fancybox-custom.less.

```
@import "fancybox";
```

along with above snippet; that way you consolidate your patches in a single place vs. scattering around your app.

Answer (score 0):

```
afterLoad   : function() {
    this.outer.prepend( '<a href="index.html"> <img src="img/logo.svg" class="logoShow"></a>' );

    }
```

Try put that code in your fancybox function. for example

```
$("a[href$='.jpg'],a[href$='.png'],a[href$='.gif']").attr('rel', 'gallery').fancybox({
openEffect  : 'none',
closeEffect : 'none',
afterLoad   : function() {
    this.outer.prepend( '<a href="index.html"> <img src="img/logo.svg" class="logoShow"></a>' );
    }
```

});

and setting the class `"logoShow"` css