# Jquery fancybox ignores options

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I know this has been asked before and I have read the other questions/answers but I'm still not able to get fancybox options to work. Maybe I'm just missing something obvious.

This is for an e-commerce site and I'm trying to have an "item out of stock" box pop up automatically when the page is loaded if the number of items left in stock is 0.

Here is the HTML generated by my template engine (server side) if the number of items in stock for the product is 0:

```
<a id="soldout_popup" title="Item is out of stock" href="/img/soldout.png"></a>
```

The fancybox() call is inside $(document).ready().

I tried it a couple of different ways. The box works perfectly, except it uses the default options. Changing options in the fancybox() call has absolutely no effect on the behavior. The title appears outside the box (not inside as specified) and the fades are about half a second (not 5 seconds as specified).

The cause of the problem in the other questions seemed to be that there was more than one fancybox() call, and I avoided doing that.

Failure 1:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#soldout_popup').fancybox({
      'hideOnContentClick': true,
      'transitionIn': 'fade',
      'transitionOut': 'fade',
      'titlePosition': 'inside',
      'speedIn':5000,
      'speedOut':5000
   });
$('#soldout_popup').trigger('click');
});
```

Failure 2:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#soldout_popup').fancybox({
      'hideOnContentClick': true,
      'transitionIn': 'fade',
      'transitionOut': 'fade',
      'titlePosition': 'inside',
      'speedIn':5000,
      'speedOut':5000
   }).trigger('click');
});
```

I tried a few other things like changing the selector to 'a#soldout_popup' which I expected not to make a difference (and it didn't) so I didn't show them.

Anyone have any idea what's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What version of fancybox you have?

And about Failure #1. trigger should be in document.ready callback, cause now it will trigger click event before 'document.ready'.

Comment: v2.1.5 (from jquery.fancybox.pack.js). To make sure i was up to date, earlier today I downloaded the distribution from the fancybox site and the file in the distro is identical to what I have deployed.

Comment: Yes, I posted the wrong code. Fails with the call inside document ready (I updated the code in my question)

Comment: So the reason(probably) why your options is not working anymore, is because v2 is completelly different from previous one. Check - http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#docs for current docs.

Comment: I would NEVER have expected them to just remove things like titlePosition, or speedIn/speedOut. I just looked quickly at the new docs. I need to dig deeper, but it appears that I now have no way to control the position of the title (equivalent to titlePosition).

Comment: Maybe this answer can help you - [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10499373/fancybox-put-title-on-top-and-stay-there)

Comment: They broke the cardinal rule of new versions, which is "don't break existing code". I now have a new version of fancybox (pushed out to me by the folks who make my CMS, and who shall not be named) and my site is messed up until I can get the old version back. I just noticed that product "enlarged view" is no longer displaying correctly. Ouch!!

Comment: It is as I suspected. You must use CSS to move the title. I don't have time to investigate, but I will mark your answer as correct. Thanks so much!!